# High query response time with SORM on small DB

Tags: sorm

I am using sorm with H2 in a small scala application.
Is normal at the first query like

```
db.query.where(filter).fetch()
```

to wait for the response 9 seconds? Is a just a warm-up time or my mistake?
I get the same behavior with Postgres.

My Db is very small, just 6 items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a warm up of the Scala's Toolbox component, utilized by SORM. It only happens on start up, so don't worry.